# per machine install of mapi custom form server(message based)

Tags: c++, installation, outlook, wix, exchange-server

I have a custom message form server which i am installing on terminal server based on windows server 2003 and 2008.
I want to do per machine install, i don't seem to get how to install it for all the domain users logging on to the machine.

If i use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815785.aspx Installform, i can install to a local form library or a personal form library which are user specific.
I don't want to install to organizational form library, if it cannot be done through msi based installer.
What do i have to do make the form server available to all users, i have tried doing MapiOpenLocalFormContainer and then InstallForm but that seems to only work for the calling user (administrator in this case)

Regards,
rui

Comment: In the end i had to install form on first launch of outlook for each user in their respective local form container and on uninstall of our software, i did all the user profile enumeration and cleared the FRMCACHE.DAT. Thanks for your comments Christopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i had to install form on first launch of outlook for each user in their respective local form container and on uninstall of our software, i did all the user profile enumeration and cleared the FRMCACHE.DAT.

Also there is a very useful registry key ForceFormReload described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919596
Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach before:

[Using Active Setup to Repair User Settings](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2011/11/using-active-setup-to-repair-user-settings.html)

You'll have to adapt it to your needs but I find it works well.  They describe how to do it in InstallShield but it applies to WiX as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make the property ALLUSERS='1' it will do the per machine installation

Comment: thanks, i am already doing per machine install through this, what i wanted was install a custom mapi form server to local form container for every logging in user, I have achieved that through the way I have mentioned above.